# After connecting to server client-side code does not response

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Whenever I execute my code, I get message at console that it's connected than after that that nothing happens.

Here is the code:

**server-side**

```
var app = require('express')()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(80);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  console.log('m connected');

  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'm joooon ' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

**client-side**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="lo">magudi</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: This looks like it should be working. Some things to try - for the client side, try adding a `socket.on('connect', function(){...});` and see if you get anything from that. Also is the browser throwing any errors in console? Also maybe try removing the `'http://localhost'` because it should work without it, or change it to `'http://localhost:80'` because thats what it should be.

Comment: @Loourr as you said i did .....

but nothing happening

socket.on('connect', function(){...}); no response coming

Answer (score 0):

On the client side, your not listening to the port.

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:80');
```